# Nice tutorial for Reproducible kernel hilbert space

Tags: vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces

I am looking for some nice tutorials related to Kernel Hilbert space. I went through lot of them but I couldn't figure out even why it is called reproducible. Any suggestions guys?

Comment: In what context did you encounter these? I have some suggestions in mind, but they depend on what your end goal is.

Comment: @Potato Kernel methods